# Result set must be in groupings - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, birt

I am making a report using java code and it is working fine ([Image Right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QitTQ.png)).
Now I want to convert it to BIRT.

Since BIRT focuses on Query, I have to change my java code to plain query. Problem is, I have a for each loop on java query where mysql doesn't have. 
I found similar query in [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9aQ-ScTqAdI&t=181s) but it did not work on me.

As of now, using plain query this is my result:
[BIRT RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQiFX.png)

What am I missing in here? Here's my code.

```
SELECT item.No_, item.Description, item_ledger_entry.Item_No_,
item_ledger_entry.Description,item_ledger_entry.Posting_Date,
item_ledger_entry.External_Document_No_, item_ledger_entry.Document_No_,
item_ledger_entry.Location_Code, item_ledger_entry.Quantity,
item_ledger_entry.Entry_Type 
FROM pbsdev3.item, pbsdev3.item_ledger_entry
where item.No_ = item_ledger_entry.Item_No_
and item.Description = item_ledger_entry.Description
group by item.No_;
```

I am a very fresh coder so I don't have much knowledge yet.

The result I wanted Look like this([It must be this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cxPt.png))
This is the [item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6V5v.png) Table and the [item_ledger_entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmAAO.png)
Help much appreciated!

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images or links to images.

Comment: Thanks, I'll change it. I'm new in SOF

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid. Won't execute on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), may return unpredictable results with older MySQL versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: @jarlh I can't change the image , not much  rep. just created my acc.

Comment: Formatted text is the way to go, i.e. skip images.

Comment: @jarlh Group by is working, it lessen the repeated data but Idk why it's not working accordingly. what could be the other reason about this?

Comment: Need more answers guys

Comment: why you are joining item table while the Item_No_ and Description from item_ledger_entry are the same ? so simple select from item_ledger_entry without joining item table would be enough (unless if there is another columns that will be included later on) . also, you don't need the GROUP BY. please provide the tables schema along with the the final results that you needed (at least the columns with a couple of rows to have a better visualization)

Comment: yes, there will be another columns needed that's why I joined them, anyway I'll be posting the schema image and the result I need also. 
(just edited it please view it thanks)

Comment: please see edited. Thanks @iSR5

Comment: @AyukNayr I guess I was right, even though the pictures not showing everything we need. But it seems that you only need to select columns from  item_ledger_entry. So, SELECT columns FROM item_ledger_entry. This is enough. Just you need to add the columns in the order that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your query is good working good. Make sure you are using Table instead of grid. Table is better than grid when it comes to multiple data.
And by the way, you don't need that groupings.

Comment: I just changed this into table last week and it's working good now. sorry I forgot to update this post. Anyway, thanks!